why two different rotation matrices give a same result when dot product them to a vector?
I have two different rotation matrices and when dot product them to a vector, i get a same result for both of them. what does this mean?
here are rotation matrices and vector
vec = [-7.74299796, 7.28526622, 9.15009209]

rot_mat1 = [[ 0.39713126,  0.85165074, -0.34202014],
            [-0.81079831,  0.15097003, -0.56552114],
            [-0.4299917 ,  0.50189548,  0.7504719 ]]

rot_mat2 = [[ 0.82343558,  0.21636871,  0.52453639],
            [ 0.0429524 ,  0.89801831, -0.43785637],
            [-0.56578171,  0.38307661,  0.73016667]]

result
[ 0.,  2.203296, 13.852754]


The result is not the same:
import numpy as np

vec = np.array([-7.74299796, 7.28526622, 9.15009209])

rot_mat1 = np.array([
    [0.39713126, 0.85165074, -0.34202014],
    [-0.81079831, 0.15097003, -0.56552114],
    [-0.4299917, 0.50189548, 0.7504719]
])
rot_mat2 = np.array([
    [0.82343558, 0.21636871, 0.52453639],
    [0.0429524, 0.89801831, -0.43785637],
    [-0.56578171, 0.38307661, 0.73016667]
])

result1 = np.dot(rot_mat1, vec)
result2 = np.dot(rot_mat2, vec)

print("Result from rot_mat1:", result1)
print("Result from rot_mat2:", result2)


retunrs
Result from rot_mat1: [5.36930799e-08 2.20329601e+00 1.38527540e+01]
Result from rot_mat2: [-8.90472861e-08  2.20329601e+00  1.38527540e+01]


Thank you. The datatype of my numpy arrays was "float32" and in that situation both results are the same. Although your results are same in 2nd and 3rd components and so close in first one, too.
However the euler components of rotation matrices are so different.
